# Android Pie not fetching data from server my sql database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to get data from my database stored in server. Everything works smooth in other android versions but app is not fetching data in  android 9. are there any other requirements to handle database in android 9.

Here is database helper class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//database version
private static int db_version = 1;

//database name
private static String db_name = "quiz_level.db";

//database path string
private String db_path;


private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;

//table name
public static String TABLE_NAME = "level";

//column names

public static String CATE_ID = "cat_id";
public static String SUB_CATE_ID = "sub_cat_id";
public static String LEVEL_NO = "level_no";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
    this.context = context;

    File database = context.getDatabasePath(db_name);
    if (!database.exists()) {
        // Database does not exist so copy it from assets here
        db_path = context.getDatabasePath(db_name).toString().replace(db_name, "");

    } else {
        //if database  exist get database from path
    db_path = context.getDatabasePath(db_name).toString();

    }

}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return super.getReadableDatabase();
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    return super.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//delete database
public void db_delete() {
    File file = new File(db_path + db_name);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();

    }
}

//Create a empty database on the system
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");

    }

    boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist1) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

//Check database already exist or not
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try {
        String myPath = db_path + db_name;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    return checkDB;
}

//Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the system folder
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String outFileName = db_path + db_name;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(db_name);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}

/*
 * insert level no
 */
public void insertIntoDB(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id, int level_no) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + CATE_ID + "," + SUB_CATE_ID + "," + LEVEL_NO + ") VALUES('" + cat_id + "', '" + sub_cat_id + "', '" + level_no + "');";
    db.execSQL(query);

}

/*
 *with this method we check if categoryId & subCategoryId is already exist or not in our database
 */
public boolean isExist(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( " + CATE_ID + " = " + cat_id + " AND " + SUB_CATE_ID + " = " + sub_cat_id + ")", null);
    boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
    cur.close();
    System.out.println("---isExit  " + (cur.getCount() > 0));
    return exist;

}

/*
 * get level
 */
public int GetLevelById(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id) {
    int level = 1;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  (" + CATE_ID + "=" + cat_id + " AND " + SUB_CATE_ID + "=" + sub_cat_id + ")";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            level = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(LEVEL_NO));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return level;
}

/*
 * Update lavel
 */
public void UpdateLevel(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id, int level_no) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("update " + TABLE_NAME + " set level_no=" + level_no + " where (cat_id =" + cat_id + "  and  " + sub_cat_id + " = " + sub_cat_id + ")");
}}
```

I am still learning so any help will be appreciated its my first project in android.
Thanks